# com.telerik.widget.calendar.RadCalendarView with 2 parameters. Check the number and type of arguments

Tags: nativescript, calendarview

Calendar was working for sometime. I updated the android libraries to version 6.4.1 and it suddenly started throwing this error.

SideKick Version: 1.19.2-v.2019.11.18.2 (latest)
NativeScript CLI version: 6.4.1
CLI extension nativescript-cloud version: 1.19.3
CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits version: 0.3.5

```
<Page
  loaded="onPageLoaded"
  xmlns:calendar="nativescript-ui-calendar"
  xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

  <ActionBar backgroundColor="#BC002D" color="#FFFFFF" flat="true">
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Calendar"></Label>
  </ActionBar>
  <calendar:RadCalendar id="calendar" />
</Page>
```

Comment: Which version of calendar plugin you are using? What libraries you are referring to? If you are referring to Android Runtime, you should also make sure your plugin version is compatible with current runtime & core modules versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have nativescript-pro-ui as one of the dependencies in package.json or platforms/android/dependencies.json, it might be causing this error. As per https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-pro-ui, remove that and use nativescript-ui-calendar.